# Outlook - Out Of Office can't set

Tags: exchange, outlook

Exchange 2007, Outlook 2010
Error when setting Out Of Office (Automatic Replies) from Outlook:
Your automatic reply settings cannot be displayed because the server is currently unavailable.  Try again later.

Setting this through OWA works fine.

Autodiscover is working, and all addresses are resolvable through DNS.
Outlook profile created from scratch.
Anonymous access disabled for EWS/OWA (IIS on Exchange box).

I'm out of steam for troubleshooting.  Any ideas?

Comment: While I can't be sure which update fixed it, I did run a series of Windows Updates, and after a reboot this issue went away.

Answer (score 2):

Is this when you are changing the responder for a different account than the one you are logged into? if not then this link has a series of steps on how to troubleshoot the message you are getting. Please try them all and report back

[out of office troubleshooting](http://www.proexchange.be/blogs/exchange2007/archive/2009/07/14/your-out-of-office-settings-cannot-be-displayed-because-the-server-is-currently-unavailable-try-again-later.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to this problem with laptop users that were simultaneously connected to open wifi while wired to our network. DNS on the laptop would resolve our OWA/EWS server to the public, external IP address, but would attempt to connect using the internal NIC. Our firewall did not route that correctly and the connection would be refused.

First we fixed the wifi problem with a group policy that says if you're connected to our wired network, no wifi connections are allowed.

Second we fixed teh firewall so that connecting to one of IP's on the external interface of the firewall from inside works.